# JavaFX2 client-server via REST Json

Tags: java, json, rest, client-server, javafx

Which is the way to create a JavaFX client-server app using Json packets for the communication? I should interact in real time between two different remote JavaFX instances (like in a chat) sending from one side to the other messages Json formatted.
Any example for doing that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a high level overview of how this could be done, then you need a library for http (You want to send JSON over http, right?) and some library to work with JSON. I think JavaFX2 is not the case in this problem, you can do this in any Java app.

There is a nice thing called [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to work with http. Tutorials on their site should provide you with some tips of how to implement both server and client functionality.

To work with JSON you can use, for example, Google's GSON library. Some discussion of JSON libraries can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

At first look you need to form a Java object, representing JSON, convert in to String and pack it up into an http POST request.

Hope this will be some help.

Comment: thanks but by specifics i have to use JavaFX sending Json over http. I'm giving a try to RedFX..could this be a right way?

Comment: Possibly can. Why not. If you have a bit of time just give it a try.

Which of the three ways of communication using RedFX are you planning to use? [WebServiceClient](http://www.redfx.org/) looks relevant to your case. It uses an HttpRequest additionally implementing a functionaly for RESTful communication. Just give it a try.

BTW, there is an [example](http://www.redfx.org/samples/chat/index.html) of building a chat application in it's tutorial.